# Converting between polar and Cartesian coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

The polar coordinates $r$ and $\varphi$ can be converted to the Cartesian coordinates x and y 
by using the [[trigonometric function]]s sine and cosine:

$$x = r \cos \varphi \,$$
$$y = r \sin \varphi \,$$

The Cartesian coordinates ''$x$'' and ''y'' can be converted to polar coordinates ''r'' and ''$\varphi$'' with ''r'' ≥ 0 and ''$\varphi$'' in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$.

$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \quad$ (as in the (Pythagorean theorem) or the (Euclidean norm),

$$\varphi=\begin{cases}
\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) & \mbox{if } x > 0 \mbox{and } y \geq 0\\
\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) + 2\pi & \mbox{if } x > 0 \mbox{ and } y < 0\\
\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) + \pi & \mbox{if } x < 0 \\
\frac{\pi}{2} & \mbox{if } x = 0 \mbox{ and } y > 0\\
-\frac{3\pi}{2} & \mbox{if } x = 0 \mbox{ and } y < 0\\
\text{undefined} & \mbox{if } x = 0 \mbox{ and } y = 0
\end{cases}$$

my question is $\varphi$ could be  written in one equation by using Congruences modulo n as follows :

$$\varphi=\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) [2\pi]$$ which means there exists some integer ”k” such that $$\varphi=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})+2\cdot k\cdot \pi $$

**Can we speak of congruence modulo 2pi (for example) for angles?**

**Are there any serious references (if wikipedia would answer my question but I am suspicious ...) which I can support myself.**

I think there is discontinuity somewhere, because when we do continuously around the origin in the direct sense, $\varphi$ angle increases by $2\pi$ and therefore can not be equal to the initial value that chose. Am i right ??

Comment: yes. it can.${}$

Comment: Serious references?  Any trigonometry section of a pre-calculus textbook...  "Angle" for trigonometric functions is taken to be any real number, and values $ \ 2 \pi \ $ apart are taken to be different "names" for the same direction.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner name good one please !

Comment: Michael Sullivan, _Pre-calculus_ (9th edition) is a reasonable choice.  But there are dozens of such books and numerous reliable on-line sources as well.  This fact doesn't really require a citation.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Thanks

Comment: @Sabyasachi i don't think so it's can't be, we waiting for the professers to answsers my question Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the angles be defined up to $2k\pi$? Yes.

Can we write $\phi = \arctan(y/x)+ 2k\pi$?
Almost, but not exactly. The problem in the use of the $\arctan$ function is not (only) that the angle is defined up to multiples of $2\pi$ (which you said correctly), but also that it gives values *only* between $-\pi/2$ and $+\pi/2$.

For example, consider the point at $(-1,0)$ in Cartesian coordinates. That is, $r=1, \phi = \pi$ in polar coordinates. If we used the "function" you define, $\phi = \arctan(y/x)+ 2k\pi$, we would get:
$$
\phi = \arctan(\frac{0}{-1}) + 2k\pi = 0 + 2k\pi \ne \pi.
$$

The problem of the $\arctan$ function is precisely its codomain. Congruences can help, and are a very nice way to look at the concept of "angle", but don't solve this problem.

In a way, the definition with "multiple cases", that you wrote, is unavoidable (and it is linked to the fact that [no continuous function can map the real line into the "circle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism#Examples) of the angles).

In the applications (for example, in CS), the problem is solved by the "[atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)" function. (The article, if you want, also answers partly to your question.)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of congruence mod $2\pi$ makes perfectly good sense for real numbers (define an equivalence relation on $\mathbf{R}$ by $x \sim y$ if and only if $y - x = 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$). However, you cannot use congruence mod $2\pi$ to define the polar angle by a single formula: $\arctan(y/x) = k$ along the line $y = kx$ (with the origin removed), but the polar angle $\theta$ differs by $\pi$ on the two rays.

Incidentally, with your piecewise definition of $\varphi$ it's not easy to see $\varphi$ is a smooth function on the plane with a closed ray removed. Instead, you can use
$$
\varphi = \begin{cases}
\operatorname{arccot}(x/y) - \pi & \text{if $y < 0$,} \\
\arctan(y/x) & \text{if $x > 0$,} \\
\operatorname{arccot}(x/y) & \text{if $y > 0$,} \\
\end{cases}
$$
and then show that the first two formulas agree in the open fourth quadrant, while the last two agree in the open first quadrant. (This defines $\varphi$ as a smooth function from the slit plane with the non-positive $x$-axis removed to the interval $(-\pi, \pi)$.)